# Выравнивание after по центру

Tags: html, css

Как выравнить псевдоэлемент after по центру

```css
ul.main-menu {
    margin-top: 36px;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
li {
  display: inline;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #aaaaaa;
  margin-right: 123px;
  font-family: $fnt_rl;
}
a {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  color: #aaaaaa;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.selected:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 24px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  content: '';
  width: 115px;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #f29400;
}
```

```html
<ul class="main-menu">
  <li><a class="selected" href="index.html">Главная</a></li>
  <li><a href="about_us.html">О нас</a></li>
  <li><a href="clients.html">Клиенты</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
ul.main-menu {
    margin-top: 36px;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
li {
  display: inline;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #aaaaaa;
  margin-right: 123px;
  font-family: $fnt_rl;
}
a {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  color: #aaaaaa;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.selected:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 24px;
  left: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  content: '';
  width: 115px;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #f29400;
  margin-left: -57px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="main-menu">
  <li><a class="selected" href="index.html">Главная</a></li>
  <li><a href="about_us.html">О нас</a></li>
  <li><a href="clients.html">Клиенты</a></li>
</ul>
```